# The number of customers who visited the shop on the first day is? {WORD PROBLEM}

Tags: linear-algebra

On the opening of a new shop, the shopkeeper gave gifts to its customers on the first day. Every two customers got a pen, every $3$ customers got $2$ keychains and every $4$ customers got $3$ calendars. A total of $91$ gifts were given. The number of customers who visited the shop on the first day is?

#### Attempt:

I believe there exist multiple solutions for this question since there are only $2$ equations and $3$ variables and the fact that those variables are positive integers. If $x$ is the number of pairs that visited, $y$ number of triples and $z$ is the number of four customers that visited then:

$$x + 2y + 3z = 91 \\
2x + 3y + 4z = N(Customers)$$

There is no unique solution but I did try to find out the maximum and minimum numbers of customers possible. Hopefully my approach is right.

Since $N(Customers) = 91 + x+y+z$
$$N(Customers) \ge 122  \ \ \ | \ \ \ x= 1, y=0,z=30 \\
N(Customers) \le 182  \ \ \ | \ \ \ x=91 ,y=0,z=0$$

Is this truly the range of customers there are and is there a unique solution?

Comment: $3y$ customers at $y\geq 1$ contain at least two customers, then they also get pen(s).

Comment: When you take z=30, it means 30 groups of 4 people visited, so y can definitely not be 0. Same with the lower case.

Comment: Let $N=12$ then customers will get 6 pens, 8 keychains and 9 calendars

Comment: How could the range be so big?  The number of gifts given out is essentially strictly increasing.  Since every odd numbered customer at least gets a pen, at most you could have the same number of gifts for $N$ and $N+1$ customers, and you can only have that with a lot of conditions on $N$.

Comment: Should say, the rules are not clear.  I can't tell if the first, third, fifth, etc. get pens or if you meant the second, fourth, sixth, etc.   If the customers are, in order, $c_1, c_2, \cdots$  then how many gifts does $c_1$ get?  What about $c_2, c_3,c_4$?

Comment: The problem is somewhat confusing. It's not clear whether the customer number four will get only calendars or calendars and a pen and so forth.

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  As it stands, the rules are not clear.

Comment: The question is from a worksheet and I am not sure of its origin, but I assume the question means that the customers come in as a group and they get those many gifts, but it doesn't matter which person gets a gift

Comment: What happens if customers come one by one or in groups large than 4. Do they not get any gifts? Then the total can by anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your variable definitions is that you are treating the pairs, triples, and quadruples of customers as if they are separate, when in fact they overlap. This is what Ivan Kaznacheyeu was pointing out in the first comment.

Instead, there is only one variable: the number $n$ of customers. Then there are

- $\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor$ pairs
- $\left\lfloor\frac n3\right\rfloor$ triples
- $\left\lfloor\frac n4\right\rfloor$ quadruples

where the half-brackets denote rounding the result down to get an integer. [**Edit:** I made an assumption here: the prizes were handed out to the last customer in each group. That is why the rounding is all down. But under that assumption, there is no solution. So a different assumption needs to be made. Maybe the shop owner values their very first customer over later customers, instead of the other way around.]

This gives one equation:
$$\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor + 2\left\lfloor\frac n3\right\rfloor + 3\left\lfloor\frac n4\right\rfloor = 91$$

The rounding in that equation is a bit of a pain, so instead, try solving the equation as if it were not there:
$$\frac 12 n + \frac 23 n + \frac 34 n = 91$$
Then see how that solution needs adjusted to get the right results.